Caused by: org.redisson.client.RedisAuthRequiredException: NOAUTH Authentication required
Am facing a pesky issue when trying to authenticate redis on spring boot. Am running redis as a docker container. Here is the docker-compose file:

i can successfully authenticate the redis on the cli

Here are the spring application properties:
spring:
  data:
    redis:
      host: localhost
      port: 6379
      password: test

when i execute my application,i get the following error:
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.translateException(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1795) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1726) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1528) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.lambda$getConnection$0(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1508) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.doInLock(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1469) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1505) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getSharedConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1191) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:997) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.fetchConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:195) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:144) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:105) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:383) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:363) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:350) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisKeyValueAdapter.deleteAllOf(RedisKeyValueAdapter.java:382) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]


Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: NOAUTH HELLO must be called with the client already authenticated, otherwise the HELLO <proto> AUTH <user> <pass> option can be used to authenticate the client and select the RESP protocol version at the same time
    at io.lettuce.core.internal.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:147) ~[lettuce-core-6.3.2.RELEASE.jar:6.3.2.RELEASE/8941aea]
    at io.lettuce.core.internal.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:116) ~[lettuce-core-6.3.2.RELEASE.jar:6.3.2.RELEASE/8941aea]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.completeResult(AsyncCommand.java:120) ~[lettuce-core-6.3.2.RELEASE.jar:6.3.2.RELEASE/8941aea]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.complete(AsyncCommand.java:111) ~[lettuce-core-6.3.2.RELEASE.jar:6.3.2.RELEASE/8941aea]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.complete(CommandHandler.java:745) ~[lettuce-core-6.3.2.RELEASE.jar:6.3.2.RELEASE/8941aea]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:680) ~[lettuce-core-6.3.2.RELEASE.jar:6.3.2.RELEASE/8941aea]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:597) ~[lettuce-core-6.3.2.RELEASE.jar:6.3.2.RELEASE/8941aea]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:801) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:501) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:399) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.109.Final.jar:4.1.109.Final]
    ... 1 common frames omitted

What might be causing this issue???

I only have a suspicion here, but could you try adding username: default before password: test in the spring application properties and try again?
